# How to sort list into ascending order? sort() function not working?

Tags: python, sorting

I have started a simple code that gets an input of numbers, and then sorts those numbers into ascending order. I tried using the sort() function, but it sorts those numbers into 'alphabetical' order instead. For example:
[3,13,20] would sort into 13,20,3 as the first number digit is 1-3 and the second 2-0 and the third 3.

I have tried simply using the sort function on a list with [3,13,20] and it gives the right answer: 3,13,20
I therefore conclude that the problem is with the first part of my code.

```
inputstring = input("Enter Numbers:")
numbers = inputstring.split()
numbers.sort()
print(numbers)
```

This would result in the numbers being sorted into 3,13,20 (alphabetically) instead. Whereas:

```
list = [13,3,20]
list.sort()
print(list)
```

Would give the answer 3,13,20 (in ascending order)

Would anybody be able to help debug why the first part of my code:

```
inputstring = input("Enter Numbers:")
numbers = inputstring.split()
```

gives the wrong ascending order?

Thanks!

Comment: OMG i'm so stupid... is it because when i am using the .sort() function on 'numbers', numbers is in a str format? That is why it is sorting alphabetically!?

Comment: Your input is a list of strings, so it sorts in string-order.  Try converting your input to integers using `int()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `split` is always a `list` of strings, which are sorted differently from `ints`. You need to convert them; one way is a `list` comprehension:

```
numbers = [int(number) for number in inputstring.split()]
```

Comment: Thanks, i just realised my stupid mistake 0;!

Comment: Is the above just the same as: numbers = list(map(int,numbers))?

Comment: @ThisIsTheEndOfPineapples Practically, yes. Personally, I would prefer a `list` comprehension in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you are giving the input to the program as follows.

```
13 3 20
```

By default it will consider the input as string.

So, when you split the input, it creates a list containing `string` elements and not `integer` elements like this `['13', '3', '20']` and not `[13, 3, 20]` and that is the reason you might be seeing unexpected output.

Try this to fix it.

```
lis = input().split()
lis = [int(i) for i in lis]
lis.sort()
```